# prolog difference between [X|Y] and [X,Y]

Tags: prolog

I know that `[X|Y]` is a list where `X` is the first element and `Y` is the rest, but what about `[X,Y]`?

Comment: `[X,Y] == [X|[Y|[]]]`

Comment: You can also write things like, `[X, Y, Z|W]` which is a list whose first 3 elements are `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, and the rest (or tail) is `W`. Note that the following list notations represent the same list: `[X,Y]`, `[X|[Y]]`, `[X,Y|[]]`, and `[X|[Y|[]]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[X,Y]` is a list where `X` is the first element and `Y` is the second element; i.e. it's a list of exactly two elements.

You could also write it as `[X|[Y|[]]]`, i.e. a list where the first element `X` and the rest is another list (where `Y` is the first element and the rest is another list (which is empty)).